# Where can I see when (date, time) I joined Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page, dates

I want to know when I joined Stack Overflow.

When I am going to the visiting calendar it shows me all of the dates, even dates before I became a member.

I mean suppose I am the user of Stack Overflow since *2 years*, it should show me the date only for that date; but when I click the back button it shows more past dates. It should start from the date when I was starting Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why? It's just a calendar. The important thing is that it doesn't show actual activity if you couldn't even have been active. That would be a bug. This certainly isn't.

Comment: Hover and you shall know... Just hover your mouse over that line and it will show you the exact date/time.

Comment: As an aside: please do not use `\`code`\` for random formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply hover the cursor on the member for and it shows the **date and time** of your *First day* of member in stack overflow.[image]